# Disable earlier dates in an HTML5 Date Control based on the value of another control

Tags: jquery, html

I have two HTML5 Date controls. One is a start date and the other is an end date. I'm looking for the best way to prevent a user from selecting an end date that is earlier than the start date.

Is there an HTML5 way of doing this, or do I need to write a JQuery solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the "min" attr in the HTML5 date control and setting the end date to the value of the start date.

```
    $('#ContractStartDate').blur(function (event) {
    $('#ContractEndDate').attr('min', $('#ContractStartDate').val())});
```